# custom Form fields database schema mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, schema

I need MySQL Schema for form generation system, I have created form designer but i need to store it in MySQL.

This system can do following

- Create your own form
- Add or remove as much fields as you want
- Form will connect to a MySQL Table which is going to store form submission data

How it can be done, plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Entity-attribute-value model (EAV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model).

Example table for form data:

- ID
- Name
- Value

So for a form with 5 fields, each form would have 5 rows. Name would be the fieldname, value the filled in value.

Comment: Thanks Konerak, could you plz show me the relationship between tables which is going to store form submission. 

Do you have any other resource link on this topic